# Getting the value of another form input in the same form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form containing 2 input fields, one being hidden and a button. When I click on the button, I need to get and assign the value of the hidden form field within that same form to another div.

How do I iterate through the dom to get the value of that specific form field? I know the form input field name.

[EDIT] - I should have added that I have multiple forms with on the same page with the same elements, so I cannot use $("input[name='FORMELEMENT']"); as I have a variety of the same form names. I need to find the value of the form element in the same form as where the button is located.

Comment: You don't "iterate through the DOM" for something like this if you're using jQuery; that's the point of selectors in jQuery. You can select with specificity which element (or, elements, depending) you're looking for and deal with it/them. Pure DOM methods, on the other hand, often come down to getting all elements by type and then looking for a more specific match. The obvious alternative in DOMland is using an `id` to `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: See my update following your edit.

Comment: Note, I edited my answer to fix the `console.log`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the `input` is `type="text"` to make it easier to see the change. This doesn't affect it being a `type="hidden"` in the live example, as they both function essentially the same, except one is not visible.

**EDIT** - Note, made a change after realizing the `console.log()`s weren't working as expected.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="myhidden" value="[placeholder]"/>
    <input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Click me!" rel="the value to copy 1"/>
</form>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="myhidden" value="[placeholder]"/>
    <input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Click me!" rel="the value to copy 2"/>
</form>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="myhidden" value="[placeholder]"/>
    <input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Click me!" rel="the value to copy 3"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="mybutton"]').click(function(){
        var $hidden = $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="myhidden"]');
        console.log($hidden.val());
        $hidden.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        console.log($hidden.val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WYJRm/4

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#the-formid input[name=the-name-you-know]").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to iterate through the DOM, you're better off just giving the form elements IDs, which makes the code easier and more reliable.

And then add this function to your Javascript file

```
function copyFormValue(visibleID, hiddenID){
   visibleElement = document.getElementById(visibleID);
   hiddenElement =  document.getElementById(hiddenID);
   hiddenElement.value = visibleElement.value;
}
```

And call the function when your button is clicked.

```
onclick="copyFormValue('userName', 'userNameHidden');"
```